# Best way of doing code for "Forgotten Password"

Tags: asp.net, security, passwords

net website, i would like to implement forget password. I am using following steps

1. Form having input box for login Id and email Id and CAPTCHA
2. when user enter details and submit, at backend after validation new password is generated and replaced old password at database.
3. New passowrd is send to user at email.

Please help me whether i am doing right or not?

Is there any other secure mechanism for the same?

**[EDIT]**
Thanks, i got your reply. Really this is a secure mechanism. But here i have few doubt

1. What message should i shown to user when he enter loginId and email address at forgotten password page?
2. Whether message would be same for valid user and mallicious user?
3. Advantage of using CSRF token? Any help / link
4. When user click on link then what should i do; because as i guess user should automatically loggin into their account -then after that i have 2 choice (first) send new password automatically to user (second) new form will shown to user where user will enetr old password and new password twice?

Please help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can see why you'd want a CAPTCHA, but I'd take a different approach.

1. When a password reset is requested check that a reset has not already been requested for that account within the last *X* minutes. If a password has already been requested ignore the reset request.
2. Check the IP requesting the password reset. If that IP has requested a password reset in the last *Y* minutes ignore the request.
3. If the checks in 1 & 2 pass check the account exists. If it doesn't ignore the request.
4. If we've gotten this far generate a one time token, which expires in *Z* minutes and a password reset URL which encompasses this token. Email this to the registered email address. When the URL is loaded prompt for a new password and reset.

For those who believe that you should tell the user where the email has gone I strongly disagree. This is "information leakage", even if you do limit it to the domain name. For example say I've registered on JeffAtwoodEatsBabies.com as blowdart. If Jeff had requested a password reset for me and you showed the registration domain then he'd see idunno.org. This is my personal domain and thus Jeff would know the blowdart user is, in fact, me. This is a **bad bad** thing. I should not have to register using hotmail or gmail or whatever in order to protect myself from your code showing an email domain to all and sundry.

In addition you shouldn't be showing error messages at all. No matter what happens, a username is not actually registered, or too many requests have been made or the sky has fallen you should be telling the user that the password reset procedure has started. Informing a user that an account doesn't exist is more information leakage.

One final thing you could do is add a CSRF token to the reset request page, so it cannot be driven from other web sites.

*Followup*

So to answer your further questions.

1. What message you show is up to you. "Instructions for resetting your password have been emailed to the registered email for this account" is one idea, but really it's down to your audience.
2. Already addressed above.
3. Wikipedia is a good [starting point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). How you do it depends on your platform and is a complete other question! For ASP.NET you could look at my codeplex project, http://anticsrf.codeplex.com or look at [ViewStateUserKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.viewstateuserkey.aspx).
4. When the link is clicked I would first validate the token in the URL against the username it's being applied to then I would either allow the user to enter a new password, or generate a new one and email it. You can't prompt for the old one, as the whole point is the user has forgotten it!

Comment: what if a genuine user inputs their info but accidentally misspells it? now you've told them that their process has begun and they may not notice their error and go about their business, but never get the email and wonder why your site is broken.

Comment: Well you have to balance security against hamfisted users. It's only a choice the site admin can make, but generally I recommend that my clients come down on the side of security. Information leaks are on the OWASP Top Ten - they're not something to be taken lightly.

Comment: Thanks,

You had cleared my lot of queries.

Is there any link where i can see the demonstration of steps you have written?

Comment: Also, can you tell me procedure for validation of token id

Comment: No - it's always going to be unique per site, and I don't have one to hand to share.

Comment: Well that depends on how you how you generate them. And that is up to *you*. You could, for example, generate a guid, shove it in a database table linked to the membership ID and look it up when it arrives. But really at some point you have to start looking at how *you* are implementing your site and decide what fits with *your* workflow.

Comment: Ok, tell me one thing that if user click on the link of unique token then Is it good to make user logged in automatically; without asking login credential

Comment: I wouldn't, until the password change is complete. It depends - do I generate a new password, or allow a reset via a form. If the form then yes, I'd login after the new password was entered.

Comment: Hey blowdart, i am thinking one point; let say i got your token link and i click link for new password then it will not stop me for new password becase the only validity is token. Isn't

Comment: That comment makes no sense - so I am guessing.
So imagine a link sent via email to the registered email address like
http://showmethecodez.com/resetPassword/?token=0000-00&accountid=123456

So the reset password page gets the account from the account ID and checks the token has been issued to that account for a password reset. It invalidates the token so it cannot be reused and prompts you for a new password for the account. You could/should symmetrically encrypt the account ID, or have an indirection object reference instead, this just illustrates the idea.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why different time windows for the user request and IP request? Which one do you think should be greater, and why?

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways this has been implemented. As you said, generating a new password and sending it to the registered email address is one method. I wouldn't suggest you go that route though, as my password would be reset everytime somebody tried guessing my password.

Instead, the best thing I've seen to date is simply emailing the registered email with a link that will begin a password reset process. You may even let the user know which email address to check by showing a masked version of their email address used in registration:

> *An email was sent to `********`@hotmail.com. Please check your inbox to continue.*

Be sure to keep in consideration those of us who may forget which email address were registered with - typically a few security questions are a great way to make that information available.

Comment: +1 Consider the user registered with foo@bar.com  Any security concerns with saying "we emailed you a link at the email address you used... starts with foo@"... comments on this strategy?

Comment: @pcampbell - +1 I really like this idea, as I sometimes want to know what email I registered with, but I think a better approach is to provide the domain name instead of the email address (@hotmail.com, @yahoo.com, @gmail.com) since I think most people are likely to have the same email address, just at different providers.

Comment: I like seeing a masked version of my email address if anything. I've updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: You means first i need to validate user email and then if validation pass then send password to email.

Comment: Hemant, no. I would send the email to whatever email address is on file for that particular username.

Comment: can't we send new password automatically to user; when he click on the link at email?

Comment: Showing the domain name presents a privacy problem since in some cases, the domain name alone can identify a user.

Comment: RickNZ, mask as much as you feel is necessary :)

Comment: Hemant, you could send a new random password if you like. I would prefer getting to provide my own, but it's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 4):

I've done that recently.  When the user enters their username or email address, we generate a unique token and email it to them as part of a link.  Upon receipt of that email, they click the link, and are automatically logged in, taken to the my account screen, and prompted to reset their password.

Of course, this relies 100% on the security of the email client, but it's hard to beat from a usability perspective.

Comment: This is a great solution, just don't forget to store only a hash of the password and not the password in plain text. You should remove the captcha too, as it is not really necessary because you have to check for the match between the email and the username.

Comment: I have few questions?
1. What is the advantage of generating unique token.
2. If i redirect user to account page where user have to type new password, In this case what will happen if i automatically generate password and send email to user?

What is the reason so that we need to generate unique token and show account form to user for change password?

Comment: The difference between automatically generating a password and having the (authenticated) user enter a password, is they will remember the one they enter.  Additionally, it does not keep the password in the email, ever, in case someone later gains access to saved email later, it will not help them break it.

Comment: Ok, tell me one thing that if user click on the link of unique token then Is it good to make user logged in automatically; without asking login credential

Comment: @Hemant: yes, you can auto-log them in provided you have the token.  You see, the token IS the authentication (deferred), that was obtained through the "Forgot my password" link.  It asserts that they have access to their email account.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud check the answer to the question : [Can anyone provide references for implementing web application self password reset mechanisms properly?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/1943/13315) from [D.W.](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/971/d-w) on security.stackexchange.

It is the most complete answer I found on the subject. I also suggest you to read this article :  [Everything you ever wanted to know about building a secure password reset feature](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html)