# Forgotten password -- A token that is only usable once but isn't stored

Tags: security, authentication

This is a question about generating a token for a user to reset his/her password, without storing said token in the database. This token would be part of a "reset password" URL sent by e-mail.

[An answer posted by sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739658/542156) explains that you can send the user a token with the following information

```
name
expiration date
hash(secret + user name + expiration date)
```

The problem with this method is that the user could change his password several times before the token expires. I think this is quite bad because it means that if the user accesses the URL from a shared computer that retains history, anyone could reset our user's password (even if just for a limited amount of time).

So my question is: is it possible to have a token that is usable only once, and that is not stored in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  An easy approach to getting a one-time use token you don't have to store or manage is to offload user management to a microservice like [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) where it takes care of all the user management for you-- password reset, password storage, user profiles, authentication, etc.

For password reset here's what it would look like:

1. User initiates password reset work on a web page
2. You make API call to stormpath with user's email address or username
3. Stormpath sends out reset email to user (your "from" address, custom HTML, etc) with a link + token.  The reset token that is unique, one-time use, and expires if not used within 24 hours
4. User clicks on the link and lands on the reset page
5. You pull the token from the URL and check Stormpath for token verification
6. User submits new password
7. Stormpath sends out reset success message (your "from" address, custom HTML, etc)

You can build your own UIs in this flow or use an out of the box, customizale id site (id.mydomain.com) that Stormpath includes.

User never knows Stormpath exists and you don't have to manage or store any passwords or reset tokens.

*Full Disclosure - I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com)*

Comment: Interesting, and also answers the question, though definitely not in a way I expected!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use a slightly different token:

```
user name
expiration date
hash(secret + user name + password_hash + expiration date)
```

When the user accesses the password reset page for the first time, you can retrieve his password hash from the database, and check the hash. It matches, the user can reset his password.

When the user accesses the password reset page for the second time with the same link, it won't work: password_hash has changed, therefore the hash won't match.

**But**.... There is a problem if the user actually types his original password. In that case password_hash will stay unchanged and the token will remain valid. Because of this edge case, this solution isn't really viable.